# Stabilization of solution to one-dimensional system of PDE

Tags: simulation, stability, parabolic-pde, numerical-analysis, multiphysics

I am trying to solve numerically next PDE system:
$$\frac{\partial c}{\partial t}=\epsilon\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(\frac{\partial c}{\partial x}+\rho\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x}+\frac{vc}{1-vc}\frac{\partial c}{\partial x})$$
$$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}=\epsilon\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x}+c\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x}+\frac{v\rho}{1-vc}\frac{\partial c}{\partial x})$$
$$-\epsilon^2\frac{\partial \varphi^2}{\partial x^2}=\rho$$
with completely blocking boundary conditions at x= ±1;
$v$ and $\epsilon$ are constants.
 However, at some point of calculation the oscillations near the boundaries occur due to the too big gradients near the boundaries. I have found some information that there are several techniques for handling numerical instabilities. (Petrov-Galerkin (SUPG) or  Galerkin least-squares (GLS) method). Unfortunately all of them usually described for the case of simple Convection-Diusion equation. Can anybody help me how to adjust some of those methods (or maybe another method) for my case? Also I need to add, that problem is not in the fact that $(1-vc)$ may tended to zero in  some points.

Comment: How do you solve the non-linearity?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. I can say only, that I'm using special software for solving PDE, not my own C++ code.

Comment: You have a non-linear system of PDEs, so I wanted to know how you linearize it to be able to solve using finite elements.

Comment: Newton's method.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a finite element method to solve this problem, why not put a few grid points in the boundary layer? 1-D implementations are usually pretty trivial to create that support meshes of varying cell size.

Comment: It is highly nonlinear task, therefore it requires very dense grid which in turn leads to the quite long computation time. I have already tried to do it (increase a density of the grid near the boundaries) within the computational limits of my computer (I mean amount of RAM), however it did not give any positive results.

Comment: Maybe if you plotted the troublesome solution for us, gave the values of $\nu$ and $\epsilon$, and gave the mathematical form of the boundary conditions, we could help out a little more.

Comment: Boundary conditions can be written in the next form:
$$\frac{\partial c}{\partial x}+\rho\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x}+\frac{vc}{1-vc}\frac{\partial c}{\partial x}=0$$
$$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x}+c\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x}+\frac{v\rho}{1-vc}\frac{\partial c}{\partial x}=0$$
$$\varphi\pm\delta\epsilon\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x}=\pm v$$
where $\delta$ is a constant which measures the effective thickness of the surface insulating layer (according to the physics model).

Comment: To be honest I'm using these equations in a little bit another form (which is a little harder for analysis, for my opinion)
$$\frac{\partial cn}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial }{\partial x}(A*cn \frac{\partial }{\partial x}(-B*\phi+C*(\log{cn}-\log{(1-D*(cp+cn))}))$$
$$\frac{\partial cp}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial }{\partial x}(A*cp \frac{\partial }{\partial x}(B*\phi+C*(\log{cp}-\log{(1-D*(cp+cn))}))$$
$$\frac{\partial \phi^2}{\partial x^2}=D(cp-cn)$$

However, this system can be easely converted to previous form with simple change of variables.

Comment: Boundary conditions:
$$\mathbf{n}\cdot((A*cn \frac{\partial }{\partial x}(-B*\phi+C*(\log{cn}-\log{(1-D*(cp+cn))})))=0$$
$$\mathbf{n}\cdot((A*cp \frac{\partial }{\partial x}(B*\phi+C*(\log{cp}-\log{(1-D*(cp+cn))})))=0$$
$$\mathbf{n}\cdot(80*\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x})=0$$

Values of parameters:
A=7.26E-13
B=96485
C=2436
D=2.21E-4

Initial conditions: 
$cn$=$cp$=250;
$\phi$=3 (smoothly increasing from 0 to 3)
Oscillations: http://imgur.com/OY85XOE